# .Net HTTPWebRequest truncates URL

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, fritzbox

Maybe someone out there who can help me:

I'm coding (just for fun) with the TR064 Interface to control AVM FritzBox Routers. I try to receive the callist from the Box. When using the Browser, it works. In my .NET-code it doesn't work. I use "httpwebrequest" method. By Fiddler I could figure out the difference between GET posted by the browser (which works) and my .net code:
In .net the URL "/tr064/callist.lua&abcdefghijkl" is truncated by the sign "&". However, this is important as after the "&" sign the sid is passed which is required for authentication with the FritzBox.

Does anyone know how I can ensure that httpwebrequest will not truncate the URL after "&"?

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: Could you please add some code to your question so that we can how you are using HttpWebRequest?